# Foreach - How to print a only the third and 4th value

Tags: php

I have form with the option to add more fields.
I'd like to know if i could print the individual values of a foreach loop. 
eg. if the person added to forms and i want to print the second value how would i do that ? 
So Far what i have tried only printed the first Character.

HTML

```
<form action="careerHistoryCon.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<label for="industry[]">Industry Segmentation</label>
<input type="text" name="industry[]" id="" placeholder="Finance / Insurance ...."><br>
<p>To add another feild <a href="#" id="addMore">Click here</a> </p> <br><br>
</form>
```

JQ

```
  $("#addMore").click(function(){   
$(".form-group:last").clone().appendTo(".wrapper");  
});
```

PHP - Problem here

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $industry= $_POST['industry'];
    foreach ($industry as $key => $value) {


        echo $value[0]. '<BR>'; 
        echo $value[1]. '<BR>'; 




    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `array_slice()` to extract parts of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty near to the solution. Using foreach on an array gives you the index as key.

```
foreach ($industry as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 1) echo $value; // array starts with 0, so 1 is the second element.
}
```

or you can use an iterator

```
// using foreach
$i = 0;
foreach ($industry as $key => $value) {
    if($i == 1) echo $value;
    $i++;
}

//using for
for($i = 0; $i < count($industry); $i++) {
    if($i == 1) echo $industry[$i];
}
```

btw. since $value is the input string of the user, $value[0] would just be the first letter the user entered. Because a string is just an array of chars.

Comment: Thanks so much it work, Kinda feel like i didnt think enough about it. thanks for the help